# android data binding. How to access view via ID inside a included layout

Tags: android, data-binding, include

I have a layout includes some layouts.
One of them have a progressBar and I want to access it using data binding but I can't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:splitMotionEvents="true"
        tools:context="jp.co.sakony.activities.DiaryNewArticleActivity"
        >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/ToolBar"
            />

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

        <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/diary_new_article_scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                >

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:splitMotionEvents="true"
                    >

                <jp.co.sakony.views.contents.InputFieldDescriptionView
                        android:id="@+id/diary_new_article_input_title_description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                        app:input_field_maxLength="@integer/diary_new_article_title_max_length"
                        app:input_field_required="true"
                        app:input_field_title="@string/diary_new_article_input_title"
                        />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                        app:counterEnabled="true"
                        app:counterMaxLength="@integer/diary_new_article_title_max_length"
                        app:counterTextAppearance="@style/counterText"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
                        >
                    <jp.co.sakony.views.APEditText
                            android:id="@+id/diary_new_article_input_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:maxLength="@integer/diary_new_article_title_max_length"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/shape_edit_cursor_orange"
                            app:textLineColor="@color/orange"
                            />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <jp.co.sakony.views.contents.InputFieldDescriptionView
                        android:id="@+id/diary_new_article_input_body_description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                        app:input_field_maxLength="@integer/diary_new_article_body_max_length"
                        app:input_field_required="true"
                        app:input_field_title="@string/diary_new_article_input_body"
                        />

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                        app:counterEnabled="true"
                        app:counterMaxLength="@integer/diary_new_article_body_max_length"
                        app:counterTextAppearance="@style/counterText"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
                        >
                    <jp.co.sakony.views.APEditText
                            android:id="@+id/diary_new_article_input_body"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLength="@integer/diary_new_article_body_max_length"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/shape_edit_cursor_orange"
                            app:textLineColor="@color/orange"
                            />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <jp.co.sakony.views.contents.InputFieldDescriptionView
                        android:id="@+id/diary_new_article_input_allow_comment_description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                        app:input_field_explanation="@string/diary_new_article_input_allow_comment_explanation1"
                        app:input_field_required="true"
                        app:input_field_title="@string/diary_new_article_input_allow_comment"
                        />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                        android:id="@+id/diary_new_article_input_allow_comment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                        android:background="@drawable/selector_comment_reply_background"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_small"
                        android:text="@string/diary_new_article_allow_comment_switch_on"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_small"
                        android:theme="@style/AllowCommentSwitch"
                        />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_shadow"/>

        <include
                layout="@layout/progress_bar_masked"
                android:id="@+id/progress"
                />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

progress_bar_masked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent_grey"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
abstract public class BaseDiaryArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, TextWatcher,
    DialogOkCancelFragment.DialogOKCancellCallback {

protected ActivityBaseDiaryArticleBinding mBinding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_base_diary_article);

    // can't find progressbar.
    mBinding.progress.progressbar
}
```

mBinding.progress return View.
but I think it should return ProgressBarMaskedBinding.

**UPDATED**

I solved this problem.

progress_bar_masked.xml is in a library project.
now I moved this layout into app project and it's working.
Maybe it's a databinding bug isn't it?

Comment: why don't you try findViewById() it can be done using it

Comment: Thank you @MohamamdFatemi .
I know findViewById() works. but the data binding can exclude any findViewById() and it can be simplify code. so Im refactoring this code.

Comment: It's supposed to work like this, it looks right. So maybe you need to rebuild your project. Or the `～` could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks @tynn. I rebuild my project many times. but it's not working.
I can find generated ProgressBarMaskedBinding.java. but ActivityBaseDiaryArticleBinding can't access it.

Comment: Still the question of what `～` means or why it's there? If it's part of your layout you should remove it.

Comment: @tynn I edited codes. why I used ～ because these codes have no relation to this question.

Comment: Did you maybe use the id `progress` for another view in your layout?

Comment: @tynn No, I didn't use id progress for any view in layouts.

Comment: Give progress bar (not its parent layout) an Id, no id guarantees it doesn't become a final field in the binding.

Comment: I updated my question. I think maybe it's a bug. thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must give your include an ID:

```
    <include android:id="@+id/toolShadow" layout="@layout/toolbar_shadow"/>
```

Then access views within the included layout via the included binding:

```
mBinding.toolShadow.progressbar.setProgress(100);
```

Comment: Thanks @George. I want to access views in the progress_bar_masked.xml.
and I gave ID android:id="@+id/progress".
you mean all included layout needs ID?

Comment: Yes. The include tag generates a binding field (ProgressBarMaskedBinding in your case) in the outer binding class (ActivityBaseDiaryArticalBinding in your case). When you give it an ID, the binding system will make it a public field. If you don't, it uses a private field and uses an internal name for it. You can, for example, include the same layout several times in the same layout and this way you can access each individually.

Comment: I updated my question. I think maybe it's a bug. thank you.

Comment: did you try compiling the project when included layout is in the library? I'm wondering if this is a studio issue or gradle issue.
Also, did you have data binding enabled in the included library ?

Comment: @yigit yes, I rebuild my project many times. and dataBinding enabled included library.

Comment: I just tried this in our integration test app. Works fine.

Comment: see the sample here: https://gist.github.com/yigit/6e6071c0cc814fe1d077a24ad64856fe

Comment: FYI i tried both having the library as a module in the app or some library that comes from an external maven repository, both cases work fine.

Comment: thnaks @GeorgeMount, worked.
How did you first knew this.

Comment: @VikasPandey - Yigit and I wrote data binding for Android.

Answer (score 5):

you must wrap included view in `layout` tag

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</layout>
```

then you can access them like `ActivityMainBinding.parentview.innerview;`
hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You must give include an ID, and also implement data-binding in included file as adding:
`<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`
then you will be able to access views from included layout file